# How do I cumsum a column that resets to 0 when column greater than 0?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame and I would like to add a column of cumulative seconds since the "auger" column was greater than 0 which resets at 0 whenever the "auger" column goes above 0.

```
x = pd.DataFrame(data={
        "date": ["2021-03-22 11:01:29", "2021-03-22 11:02:29", "2021-03-22 11:03:29", "2021-03-22 11:04:29", "2021-03-22 11:05:29", "2021-03-22 11:06:29"],
        "auger": [1450.0, 1450.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1200.0, 1200.0],
        "poll_seconds": [60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60]
})
```

Is there a way to create a column called "seconds_off" which does a cumsum on the poll_seconds starting at 0 whenever the "auger" column is 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mask = x["auger"] != 0

x["count"] = x.groupby((mask != mask.shift(1)).cumsum())[
    "poll_seconds"
].cumsum()
x.loc[~mask, "count"] = 0
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
                  date   auger  poll_seconds  count
0  2021-03-22 11:01:29  1450.0            60     60
1  2021-03-22 11:02:29  1450.0            60    120
2  2021-03-22 11:03:29     0.0            60      0
3  2021-03-22 11:04:29     0.0            60      0
4  2021-03-22 11:05:29  1200.0            60     60
5  2021-03-22 11:06:29  1200.0            60    120
```